# array lists - how to do them and make them work

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an arraylist called cardata with 4 car objects held in it.

- Ford, Focus, P
- Ford, Focus, D
- Nissan, Leaf, E
- Tesla, Model X, E

I then need to create a method called `printCars(allCars:ArrayList<Car>)` that prints out this information to then be called with cardata as a parameter. This is what I have so far.

```
public class CarTester 
{
    public ArrayList<String> carData = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Car cd1 = new Car("Ford", "Focus", FuelType.P);
    Car cd2 = new Car("Ford", "Focus", FuelType.D);
    Car cd3 = new Car("Nissan", "Leaf", FuelType.E);
    Car cd4 = new Car("Tesla", "Model X", FuelType.E);
    {
        carData.add(cd1);
        carData.add(cd2);
        carData.add(cd3);
        carData.add(cd4);
    }

    public String printCars(ArrayList<Car> allcars)
    {
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To print the data you can loop through elements using a for loop

```
public void printList(List<Car> cars) {
    for (Car car: cars) {
       // Customize this row to print what you like
       System1.out.println("The car " + car.getModel());
    }
}
```

If you like to create a string from the list of cars you can  also use streams

```
public String convertListToString(List<Car> cars) {
    return cars.stream()
        .map(car -> "The car " + car.getModel())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

---

There is also an error defining the list.
It must be a List of Car not a List of String. Change the following:

```
 public ArrayList<String> carData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
 // From String to Car
 public ArrayList<Car> carData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: any idea how to fix my arraylist as well? cause it wont let me add the car objects i created to the arraylist CarData but i dont know how to add them.

Comment: Additionnally, the code has useless curly brackets (surrounding the carData.add part). Also, the code should declare `public List<> carData = new ArrayList<Car>();`, using the diamond operator and Liskov principle.

Comment: @mikasa7711 check the updated answer